# FormData list data not able to post in controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net-core

I am using dot net core 7. here i have a form that upload multiple file
there is not possible to use in direct i have a this different class for upload file with other data

Note : these data are not fix some time it should be multiple row
problem is only with file all other data are posting. only file is not getting in controller

```
  public class RegAttachedDto
    {
        public int? DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? RegFIleFile { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class OrganisationRegDto
    {
        public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int RegdCategoryId { get; set; }
        public double AuthorizedCapital { get; set; }
        public double PaidupCapital { get; set; }
        public double IssuedCapital { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociateMember { get; set; }
        public IList<RegAttachedDto> regAttachedDtos { get; set; }
    }
```

```
let regAttachedDtosArr = new Array();
let regAttachedDtosfn = () => {
    $('#businessRegDocument  .trdata').each(function (i, row) {
        let DocumentTypeId = $(this).find("td .DocumentTypeId").val();
        let RegFIleFile = $(this).find("td .DocTypeName")[0].files[0];

        let DocDescription = $(this).find("td .DocDescription").val();
        if (RegFIleFile != 'undefined' && DocumentTypeId != '' && DocDescription != '') {
            regAttachedDtosArr.push({
                RegFIleFile: RegFIleFile,
                DocumentTypeId: DocumentTypeId,
                DocDescription: DocDescription

            });
        }
    });
}
```

```
let SendToDb = () => {
        regAttachedDtosArr = [];
        regAttachedDtosfn();
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("Name", $("#Name").val());
        formdata.append("RegdCategoryId", $("#RegdCategoryId").val());
        formdata.append("AuthorizedCapital", $("#AuthorizedCapital").val());
        formdata.append("PaidupCapital", $("#PaidupCapital").val());
        formdata.append("IssuedCapital", $("#IssuedCapital").val());
        formdata.append("IsAssociateMember", $("#IsAssociateMember").is(':checked'));
        formdata.append("regAttachedDtos", JSON.stringify(regAttachedDtosArr));
        console.log(regAttachedDtosArr); //file are show in this console
        console.log(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controllername/actionName',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formdata
        }).done((res) => {

            toastr.success("Success", {
                timeOut: 8000
            });

        }).catch((ex) => {

            toastr.error(ex);
        });

    }, function () { });
}
```

```
$('#regorgForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   
        SendToDb();
    
});
```

```
  public IActionResult actionName([FromForm]OrganisationRegDto regDto)
        {
            
            var regAttachedFiles = HttpContext.Request.Form["regAttachedDtos"];
            var boardMember = HttpContext.Request.Form["boardMemberDtos"];
            var regAuthority = HttpContext.Request.Form["regAuthorityDtos"];
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; // here files are 0
            
            return View("Index");
        }
```

I had try doing multipart on request type and add and removing JSON.stringify

i.e formdata.append("regAttachedDtos", JSON.stringify(regAttachedDtosArr));
and
formdata.append("regAttachedDtos", regAttachedDtosArr;

contentType: false, and also try using this
i also try to send data using this

if i remove processData: false no data will get  in controller
if make it true then file will give error

Comment: after research i got a solution in html file i gave a name like 
name="regAttachedDtos [0].RegFIleFile"
name="regAttachedDtos [1].RegFIleFile"